# Print JSON parsed object?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, printing

I've got a javascript object which has been JSON parsed using `JSON.parse` I now want to print the object so I can debug it (something is going wrong with the function). When I do the following...

```
for (property in obj) {
    output += property + ': ' + obj[property]+'; ';
}
console.log(output);
```

I get multiple [object Object]'s listed. I'm wondering how would I print this in order to view the contents?

Comment: as a sidenote, for (property in obj) will list all properties, even the inherited ones. So you will get a lot of extraneous one cominng for Object.prototype and any 'mother class'. This is unconvenient with json objects. You have to filter them with hasOwnProperty() to get only the properties that this object owns.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Most debugger consoles support displaying objects directly. Just use

```
console.log(obj);
```

Depending on your debugger this most likely will display the object in the console as a collapsed tree. You can open the tree and inspect the object.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that in chrome (and perhaps other browsers) when combined with a string like this: `console.log("object: " + obj)` it does not display the object, but instead will output "object: [Object obj]".

Comment: @Shahar `console.log("object: %O", obj)` (Chrome) or  `console.log("object: %o", obj)` (Firefox|Safari) will give you access to the object details, see my answer below.

Comment: @DaveAnderson good shot for the object formatting in the console.

Comment: @Shahar thanks, yours was the information I needed. Should be added to the answer.

Comment: In addition to @DaveAnderson 's method, using a comma to separate strings from objects can also work: `console.log("My object: ", obj)`

Comment: The better solution to the here mentioned methods is simply `console.log({obj})`. (better as in better readable output and less to write, but still clear syntax)

Comment: @Shahar Exactly. thats why I've reached in this page.

Comment: @SourceOverflow, not exactly. You wrapped `obj` in extraneous `{...}` braces which serves to create a harmless, but somewhat annoying, layer of indirection. `{foo}` is ECMA shorthand for _an object literal with a key `foo` whose value is the scoped variable `foo`_, i.e. producing the same thing as `{foo: foo}`. The actual best solution is `console.log(obj)`, or `console.log('My text:', obj)` (note the auto-concatenation that happens without need for string format specs). Of course, if you're already in the console REPL, just type `obj` then ENTER ↩—no `console.log` boilerplate necessary…

Comment: @EzekielVictor Yes, that's the point ^^ That way you know what variable is output in the log. With one it's not that useful, but when having multiple you can just do `console.log({i, array, element})` and get a complete picture without having to add text to it that describes what it is. Of course only works with well named variables.

Answer (score 674):

You know what JSON stands for?  *JavaScript Object Notation*.  It makes a pretty good format for objects.

`JSON.stringify(obj)` will give you back a string representation of the object.

Comment: I'm surprised this answer is at the bottom...... This should be the accepted answer :-)

Comment: What if you don't want a string representation, but rather the object as it would appear in a code editor?

Comment: @SuperUberDuper: ...Then you wouldn't be trying to build a string representation, now, would you.  :)

Comment: I believe SuperUberDuper was asking if the object could be logged or viewed without converting it to a string. If viewing in the browser the DOM needs an element, you can stringify json so and set an elements contents  innerHTML to that string to view it on the page.

Comment: For example: 
import Json from './data.json';
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(Json);

Answer (score 67):

If you want a pretty, multiline JSON with indentation then you can use `JSON.stringify` with its 3rd argument:

> `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])`

For example:

```
var obj = {a:1,b:2,c:{d:3, e:4}};

JSON.stringify(obj, null, "    ");
```

or

```
JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);
```

will give you following result:

```
"{
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": {
        "d": 3,
        "e": 4
    }
}"
```

In a browser `console.log(obj)` does even better job, but in a shell console (node.js) it doesn't.

Answer (score 56):

try `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`

```
console.dir(obj);
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir) says `console.dir()` is supported by:

- FF8+
- IE9+
- Opera
- Chrome
- Safari

Comment: Only available in IE9+

Comment: `console.dir()` is also available in FF8+, Opera, Chrome and Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.dir

Comment: Great! This is the best solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: what about node js ?

Comment: good , but does not support string concatenation like log("string " + variable)

Answer (score 47):

to Print JSON parsed object just type 
 `console.log( JSON.stringify(data, null, "    ") );`
and you will get output very clear

Answer (score 31):

Use string formats;

```
console.log("%s %O", "My Object", obj);
```

Chrome has [Format Specifiers](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object) with the following;

- `%s` Formats the value as a string.
- `%d` or `%i` Formats the value as
  an integer.
- `%f` Formats the value as a floating point value.
- `%o` Formats the value as an expandable DOM element (as in the
  Elements panel).
- `%O` Formats the value as an expandable JavaScript
  object.
- `%c` Formats the output string according to CSS styles you
  provide.

Firefox also has [String Substitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_string_substitutions) which have similar options.

- `%o` Outputs a hyperlink to a JavaScript object. Clicking the link opens an inspector.
- `%d` or `%i` Outputs an integer. Formatting is not yet supported.
- `%s` Outputs a string.
- `%f` Outputs a floating-point value. Formatting is not yet supported.

Safari has [printf style formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_4_0.html)

- `%d` or `%i` Integer
- `%[0.N]f` Floating-point value with N digits of precision
- `%o` Object
- `%s` String

Comment: nice reference answer

Comment: %O is really helpful

Comment: FYI, in Firefox, %O now seems to output as an expandable object inside the console.

Answer (score 6):

Nice and simple:

```
console.log("object: %O", obj)
```

Comment: could you please describe what does %O for? should it be O specifically? - your solution work like a charm

Comment: O stands for object, so as long as the object can be printing as a string, it should be printed with no issues. This has helped me troubleshoot in many cases where I wasn't sure where the error is

Comment: I forgot to inform here, actually we don't need to use %O. We can directly use console.log("object: ", obj) thank you @mbenhalima

Comment: So then this is the same as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
console.info("CONSOLE LOG : ")
console.log(response);
console.info("CONSOLE DIR : ")
console.dir(response);
```

and you will get this in chrome console :

```
CONSOLE LOG : 
facebookSDK_JS.html:56 Object {name: "Diego Matos", id: "10155988777540434"}
facebookSDK_JS.html:57 CONSOLE DIR : 
facebookSDK_JS.html:58 Objectid: "10155988777540434"name: "Diego Matos"__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to debug why not use console debug

```
window.console.debug(jsonObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple function to alert contents of an object or an array .
Call this function with an array or string or an object it alerts the contents.

**Function**

```
function print_r(printthis, returnoutput) {
    var output = '';

    if($.isArray(printthis) || typeof(printthis) == 'object') {
        for(var i in printthis) {
            output += i + ' : ' + print_r(printthis[i], true) + '\n';
        }
    }else {
        output += printthis;
    }
    if(returnoutput && returnoutput == true) {
        return output;
    }else {
        alert(output);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4];
print_r(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will display complete json data in alert box

```
var data= '{"employees":[' +
'{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{"firstName":"Anna","lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones" }]}';

json = JSON.parse(data);
window.alert(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in js on a server, just a little more gymnastics goes a long way... Here's my ppos (pretty-print-on-server):

```
ppos = (object, space = 2) => JSON.stringify(object, null, space).split('\n').forEach(s => console.log(s));
```

which does a bang-up job of creating something I can actually read when I'm writing server code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it was never made officially, [but I've added my own `json` method](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/4167b548a6921399b3a6bbcc1bd1e08a) to `console` object for easier printing stringified logs:

> Observing Objects (non-primitives) in javascript is a bit like quantum mechanics..what you *"measure"* might not be the real state, which already have changed.

```js
console.json = console.json || function(argument){
    for(var arg=0; arg < arguments.length; ++arg)
        console.log(  JSON.stringify(arguments[arg], null, 4)  )
}

// use example
console.json(   [1,'a', null, {a:1}], {a:[1,2]}    )
```

Many times it is needed to view a stringified version of an Object because printing it as-is (raw Object) will print a "live" version of the object which gets mutated as the program progresses, and will not mirror the state of the object at the logged point-of-time, for example:

```js
var foo = {a:1, b:[1,2,3]}

// lets peek under the hood
console.log(foo) 

// program keeps doing things which affect the observed object
foo.a = 2
foo.b = null
```