# how to print json array in jquery with ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am newbie in JSON. i just started learning JSON before 30 mins.

i want to print JSON array in jquery.

```
 $.ajax({
                url : '/exp/resp.php',
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
              //  data : 'uname='+uname+'&pass='+pass,
                success : function (data)
                {
                    alert(data);

                }
            });
```

now it's printing **abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno**. so i want to print it separate like abc def ghi etc.. i referred [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127455/how-print-json-array-in-javascript) but it didn't help...

Comment: `data` is not a "JSON array". Even though the response is JSON-encoded data, jQuery will have parsed the data already. So `data` is just a normal JavaScript array. The question/problem itself has nothing to do with JSON.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if `data` is an array then

```
alert(data.join(' '));
```

Comment: tnx for answer.. i want to ask you one more thing that if i want to access it like data.1, data.2 something like this? how ot do it? i m returning it from php using json_encode($array)..

Comment: @pandit you can use the index to access it.. like `data[0]`, `data[1]`... `data[data.length - 1]`

Comment: thanks.... and one more question that if i want to send json object from php file then how send?

Comment: @pandit not sure... not a PHP guy... i think there is a `json_encode` call

Comment: @pandit Arun is right, you can convert an `array` into a json string with `json_encode` and you can convert an json string into an `array` using `json_dncode`...

Answer (score 16):

Why not print something generic like:

```
JSON.stringify(data);
```

This should work with either an object or an array.

Comment: it's not printing anything

Comment: right, this one just converts the object into a string. If you want to print it you have to use "console.log(JSON.stringify(data));" or "alert(...);"  or whatever...

Answer (score 2):

Since your `data` is an `array` Check the following tutorial

Join the elements of an array into a string:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = fruits.join();
```

The result of energy will be:

```
Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango
```

Have a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

For your code use [Arun P Johny's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) solutions

```
alert(data.join(' '));
```

Comment: tnx for answer in detail.. i want to ask you one more thing that if i want to access it like data.1, data.2 something like this? how ot do it? i m returning it from php using json_encode($array)..