# How to display data via $.get function using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, getjson

I am having this issue I have been struggling with for sometime and now I need help: 
I have the following array

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["idMake"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["modelName"]=>
    string(6) "Legend"
    ["modelYear"]=>
    string(4) "1986"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["idMake"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["modelName"]=>
    string(3) "MDX"
    ["modelYear"]=>
    string(4) "2000"
  }
}
```

How can I use it the `$.get()` function via jQuery in order to have something like this:

```
id   Model      Year
  1    Legend     1986
  2    MDX        2000
```

I have already tried the following:

a process.php file:

```
<?php
require 'DataLayer.class.php';
$dl = new DataLayer();

//get car make models
$models = $dl->getCarModels($id);
if(isset($models)){
    echo json_encode(json_encode($models));
}
else{
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

the getCarModels function:

```
public function  getCarModels($id){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT  * FROM model WHERE idMake=? ORDER BY modelName");
    $stmt->execute(array($id));
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

Javascript function called upon clicking on some links

```
function getCarModels(id, make){
    $.get(process.php, function(data){       
        var models = $.parseJSON(data); 
        for(var model in models.model.modelName){ // I got stuck here

        } 
    });
}
```

Hope this makes any sense to someone. Thanks.

Just find out some similar issue at this link: [php multidimensional array into jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383919/php-multidimensional-array-into-jquery) I am giving a try.

---

Like I said from the start, my issue is quite similar to the one posted at this link [php multidimensional array into jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383919/php-multidimensional-array-into-jquery). My only question is that I really don't know the reason why they use the json_encode() function twice as all I did to make it work properly is to remove one of the json_encode() functions.

Will appreciate some explanation of the reason why I used only jsan_encode() function to get the result I wanted while in most tutorial it has been two time before outputting the data.

Thanks again.

Comment: It might help to use firebug to see the contents of `models` as well as the contents of the GET response from the server.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion: I have the following string: [{"id":"1","idMake":"1","modelName":"Legend","modelYear":"1986"},{"id":"2","idMake":"1","modelName":"MDX","modelYear":"2000"}] not too sure how I can handle this type of string instead of an array

Comment: oi, oi what's is returned is a json array, you can use Jquey $.each method to  loop through it. if you are not sure use firebug debug mode to see what happens as suggested by @justin

Comment: Well, I have an empty response using the firebug debug mode. Quite weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use parseJSON within jQuery ajax, jQuery will already handle that. Your data is an array of objects. Here's example to loop over it with `$.each`

Your `getCarModels()` function isn't set up to send data

```
function getCarModels(id, make){

     var dataToServer={ id: id, make: make};/* need to match these keys to $_GET keys in php*/
    $.get(process.php, dataToServer, function(data){       
        $.each( data, function(i, item){
            $('body').append('<p>'+item.modelName+'</p>');
        })
    });
}
```

The php has issues also , it doesn't appear you are looking for $_GET from the ajax to pass to your query methods. I don't recognize the framework functions used in your php but to pass the ID to getCarModels in pphp you would need something like:

```
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 //get car make models
 $models = $dl->getCarModels($id);
```

Comment: without the parseJSON, 'alert(data)' gives me '"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"idMake\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"Legend\",\"modelYear\":\"1986\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"idMake\":\"1\",\"modelName\":\"MDX\",\"modelYear\":\"2000\"}]"'  I guess it is because of the 'json_encode(json_encode($models))' I used in the process.php file.  I found a quite similar issue at this page: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383919/php-multidimensional-array-into-jquery). I keep having undefined value as I do '$.each(models, function(){
   alert(models[0]['modelName']);
 })'

Comment: use `json` as datatype in ajax or use $.getJSON, also if issues add header  application/json in php and mke sure nothing else is being echo'd