# angular.copy() returning Object when source is Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want to create a copy of my `arguments` inside a logging function using `angular.copy()`.

Since the `arguments` is already an Array, I expected to get an Array but it returned Object instead of Array.

```
$scope.log = function(argN) {
    console.log("arguments", arguments, angular.copy(arguments));
    if (typeof(console) !== 'undefined') {
        console.log.apply(console, angular.copy(arguments));
    }
}
```

1. Is this some sort of standard practice of copying?
2. How can I get Array instead of Object?

Comment: `arguments` is not an array.

Answer (score 2):

`arguments` is not an array but array like. To do a shallow clone of `arguments`, use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`. That will create an array of all the arguments. From there, to get a deep clone, use `angular.copy`.

```js
var foo = angular.module('foo', []);

foo.controller('bar', function($scope) {
   $scope.trace = function() {
       var clonedArguments = angular.copy(arguments);
       console.log(clonedArguments);
       var clonedArgs = angular.copy(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
       console.log(clonedArgs);
   };
  $scope.trace(1, 'foo', { bar: 27 })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="foo" ng-controller="bar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I think `console.dir()` maybe what you are looking for after reading this

[Print JSON parsed object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933217/print-json-parsed-object)